# Satis est: de quadam re aut cuiusdam rei?

Tags: grammar-choice

"Satis est!" significare potest aliquid sufficere vel ob quandam causam saturatum esse ("Iam satis est! Tace!"), ut Anglice dicitur "enough!".

Si autem causa exponenda est, quomodo melius dicitur: "satis est *de causa*" aut "satis est *causae*"?

Mihi "satis est de causa" melius videtur, sicut in *loqui de quadam re*, sed (oblitus sum ubi) me hanc sententiam cum genitivo casu scriptam olim vidisse credo.

Comment: Potesne nobis exemplum dare illius "causae"? Si de sermone nimis longo loquimur, mihi videtur dici licere "satis de" (e.g. "sed satis de Graecis", scilicet "dictum est" vel "verborum"). Sin alia loquimur de re, arbitror genetivum opus esse.

Comment: Casus quem in mente haberam ut questionem istam fecissem est "satis est de nugis tuis" vs. "satis est nugaram tuarum". Nescio vero utrum latinius sit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uti summam faciam quae Sebastiānus exposuit, utraque locūtiō aliud sibi volt:

1. **satis est (mihi) huijus rei** = *huijus rei satis, affatim (ego) habuī aut habeō. benignē prōpōnis, sed nōn opus est plūs vel amplius;*
2. **satis est dē hāc rē** = *hāc dē rē satis dictum est (nōn mihi tantum, sed cuivīs in ūniversum). nōlō amplius audīre aut dīcere. satis hoc tractāvimus; trānseāmus ad aliud.*

Itaque sī ea dē quīs locūtī estis nūgās esse putās, hoc (2) dīcis; sī satis ūnā nūgātī estis, illud (1).

Answer (score 5):

Plura lexica adhibui ([Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsatis), [Gaffiot](https://gaffiot.org/83265), [Georges](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/satis)), sed una in re omnia consentiunt: ad notandam rem cuius talem copiam habemus qualem volumus (nisi etiam maiorem copiam), genetivo nos uti oportet. Ex quo efficitur, ut scribendum sit (ut exemplum sumam de quo supra mentionem fecisti): **satis est nugarum tuarum**. Ecce satis superque exemplorum horum ipsorum verborum «satis nugarum» inveniuntur [apud Google Books](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22satis%20nugarum%22&tbm=bks).

Nihilo setius interdum scriptum invenies: «satis de aliqua re». Quae verba autem significant *satis sermonis* de ea re iam habitum esse; hoc est, de ea re *satis iam dictum* esse vel *satis verborum* iam factum (facta?) esse. Velut complures scriptores apud Google Books qui verbis [«satis de his nugis»](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22satis%20de%20his%20nugis%22&tbm=bks) utuntur!